# How to reset raspberry pi on laptop?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, putty, ping, reset

I have a RPI which I borrowed from a friend's friend. So I don't know whether he has changed the id and password for it. Because when I am trying the default

```
id : pi
password : raspberry
```

the raspberry is giving a message `access denied`. So now I need to reset it so that I can restore it to default. I saw many tutorials that asks me to connect it to some monitor and mouse. But the problem is I don't have none of those. So is there a way to reset it from my laptop to restore its default configuration.

These were the steps that I followed from the beginning :

1. Downloaded the raspberry stretch
2. Flashed my sd card using winDiskImager
3. Inserted my card to the RPI
4. Got the IP address of my pi using `ping -a raspberrypi`
5. Started the connection using PuTTy
6. The terminal asked me for the id and password, on entering the default I got the message access denied

So is there any way to reset my PI using laptop?

**EDIT:**
When tryin to connect via PUTTY, this is what I am getting

```
login as: pi
pi@169.254.180.202's password:
Access denied
pi@169.254.180.202's password:
```

Comment: This is very confusing - you say "Downloaded the raspberry stretch" Raspbian-Stretch is not the current download, although a dedicated search could find it. From where? Why? Try asking a single question.

Comment: **DO NOT** use winDiskImager - follow one of the recommended installation methods.

Comment: If you are writing a new image it doesn't matter what your friend's friend (or anyone else in the universe) may have done.

Comment: @Milliways yes i got the stretch from a backup available on Internet.

Comment: Tell me one thing if I have inserted a new sd card then the id and password is supposed to be reset to default or will the raspberry contain the previous id and password

Comment: If you reflash the card everything your friend changed is gone. So you already reset the pi by that.

Comment: *from a backup available on Internet* - whose backup? get the original image - and why not go buster?

Comment: @Milliways - why not use windiskimager? it used to be the way to go (back several years ago)

Comment: `connect it to some monitor and mouse` - any television with HDMI will do ... and you DONT need a mouse, you need a KEYBOARD - you should be able to buy one for very few units of your currency

Comment: @jake then why are the default pi and raspberry giving access denied

Comment: @JaromandaX the tutorial which I am following for my self driving car https://www.udemy.com/course/selfdrivingcar

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have access to any of those TV, monitor or mouse. I just have my laptop with me

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - how will that tutorial help you with your problem? Is that where you got the image? perhaps the image they supply has different default user/pass - you should read the tutorial **very carefully** if you got the image from some bogus link in it

Comment: @JaromandaX the instructor used pi and raspberry and it worked for him

Comment: A suggestion, install the original Raspbian image and install packages by yourself.

Comment: then you must've done *something wrong™*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have already flashed the SD Card with Raspbian Stretch all the installation of your friends friend is lost. So you have to start again from scratch. Just [download Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and install it as described at [Installing operating system images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md). Then enable ssh as shown in [SSH (Secure Shell)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md). With this image you definitely have user **pi** with password **raspberry**.

If you flash another image getting from everywhere on the internet you have to know what username and password its author has given to it. Read its installation guide or ask the author.

Comment: Since I am a beginner, so I thought that the changes to the user my friend made will remain until we don't change it again. I did not know the fact that once you install new OS everything is reset, as RPI does not have any memory of its own